# Change Radio Input Value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some radio inputs and their values have `<a class="green none" href=""` in them. I also have a section, a `div` with classname `toggleclass` precisely, and when that div is clicked, I need that `none` to be removed from class attribute.

The HTML

```
<ul class="ulitems">
    <li><input class="liitems" type="radio" name="items" value="<a class="green none" href="http://www.google.com" title="Google" target="_blank">Google</a>"></li>
    <li><input class="liitems" type="radio" name="items" value="<a class="green none" href="http://www.yahoo.com" title="Yahoo" target="_blank">Yahoo</a>"></li>
    <li><input class="liitems" type="radio" name="items" value="<a class="green none" href="http://www.bing.com" title="Bing" target="_blank">Bing</a>"></li>
    <li><input class="liitems" type="radio" name="items" value="<a class="green none" href="http://www.facebook.com" title="Facebook" target="_blank">Facebook</a>"></li>
    <li><input class="liitems" type="radio" name="items" value="<a class="green none" href="http://www.twitter.com" title="Twitter" target="_blank">Twitter</a>"></li>
</ul>
```

Some of the JavaScripts I tried

```
$('.toggleclass').on("click",function() {
    $('.ulitems').find(' none').remove();
});
```

also,

```
$('.toggleclass').on("click",function() {  
$('.liitems').attr("value").remove(' none');
});
```

and also,

```
$('.toggleclass').on("click",function() {
    $('.liitems').attr("value").find('class="green none"').replaceWith('class="green"');
});
```

But, that seems not to work at all. Can you please guide me?

**To be exact, I need to save HTML value ,`a class="green none" href=""...` in this case, with a radio select submit. And, I want to give users an option to remove that `none` class, (or the whole class attribute if removing `none` isn't possible) when they click on a button.**

Regards

Comment: I think you need to show us the bigger picture. You are embedding HTML codes in your input values, which is not how input fields should be used. While it would be possible to answer your question, and make it work, I think you'll get a better answer if you tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @FrederikWordenskjold I am trying to save an `<a class="green none" href=""` value with a radio select submit. And, I want to give users an option to remove that `none` class when they click on a button.

Comment: I get that. I was looking for an explanation of what you wanted to solve, not technically, but from a users point of view. I think there's an opportunity for you to learn a few things here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7eqt/)

```
$('.toggleclass').on("click", function () {
    alert($('.liitems').val().replace('none',''));
});
```

replace `alert();` with this one: [**checkout updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7eqt/1/)

```
$('.toggleclass').on("click", function () {
    $('.liitems').val($('.liitems').val().replace('none', ' '));
});
```

Comment: That's not changing the value in DOM, however the alert is showing fine.

Comment: Oh that's a quick response, fine just updated the answer, You can replace the alert with the second one.